# Issues changing state using buttons with React.js

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to change a state in my App.js using an onClick listener that take in the value of an DOM element to grab a value. This will allow me to change what jsx is rendered to the DOM. This is similar to changing pages on a website however, I want this to be all done in one area.

So far however, I have been getting an undefined value for the DOM element.

I believe that the problem may stem from how I have written my function or how I have passed it into my Navbar component.

State

```
 state = {
    page: 'Home'
  }
```

Change Page function

```
 changePage = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    this.setState({
      page: value
    })
  }
```

How it is being passed in to the Nav Component

```
<Navbar changePage={this.changePage} value1={this.state.page} link1={"About"} link2={"Portfolio"} link3={"Contact"} />
```

The Nav Component

```
import React from 'react';

function Navbar(props) {

    return (
        <div className='row'>
            <h5 className='col s4 waves-effect center-align' name={props.link1} value={props.link1} onClick={(event) => props.changePage(event)}>{props.link1}</h5>
            <h5 className='col s4 waves-effect center-align' name={props.link2} value={props.link2} onClick={props.changePage}>{props.link2}</h5>
            <h5 className='col s4 waves-effect center-align' name={props.link3} value={props.link3} onClick={props.changePage}>{props.link3}</h5>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

When I click on the first  in the Nav Component, I expect that using the function I passed to it from the parent Component, it will grab the value and change the state to the value. Instead, I get a value of undefined.

Comment: a `h5` element's value would be `innerText` I think. But instead of that you should just pass what you want through in the callback itself. that way its more explicit. `onClick={(e) => props.changePage(e, link1)}` that way you just give the value, a potential bug in your code could be if something edits the innerText of the element, your code wouldn't work. Better to keep it explicit / more directive :)

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_value.asp

```
For <button>, <input> and <option> elements, the value attribute specifies the initial value of the element.

For <li> elements, the value attribute sets the value of the list item (for ordered lists). The next list items will increment from that value.

For <meter> elements, the value attribute specifies the current value of the gauge.

For <progress> elements, the value attribute specifies how much of the task has been completed.

For <param> elements, the value attribute specifies the value of the parameter.
```

For `<h>` tags, I believe `value` is not an applicable attribute, therefore you get "undefined" https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hn.asp

What you can do is to update your method in a way that it accepts a value

```
 changePage = (value) => {
    this.setState({
      page: value
    })
  }
```

and for your `<h>` tags you can update onClick method in a way that, you pass the value directly to it

```
onClick={() => props.changePage(props.link1)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like I was saying in the comments, you are trying to access an attribute that doesn't exist on that element, can you change the element to a different one? yes, is that the best way to handle getting the new page? no probably not. I would clean the code up a little. You should be more directive with how it works, pass explicit values to update, this will harden your code and be less error prone.

Also, I turned the links into an array so that all you need to do now to add a new link is just add one more string in the `links` array and the rest will happen for you :)

```
function Navbar({onClick, links, activeLink}) {
    return (
        <div className='row'>
            { links.map( link => (
              <a href={`/${link}`}
                 onClick={(e) => onChange(e, link)}
              >
                <h5 className={`col s4 waves-effect center-align${activeLink === link ? ' active' : ''}`}
                    name={link}
                >
                  {link}
                </h5>
              </a>
            )}
        </div>
    )
}
```

then your change page handler

```
changePage = (e, page) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.setState({ page })
}
```

The way to use the `NavBar` component would be

```
<Navbar 
  onChange={this.changePage}
  activeLink={this.state.page}
  links={["About", "Portfolio", "Contact"]}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using a button to wrap your headings, and executing the function instead of returning it:

```js
<button
  name={props.link1}
  value={props.link1}
  onClick={(event) => { props.changePage(event); }}
>
  <h5 className='col s4 waves-effect center-align'>{props.link1}</h5>
</button>
```